Get lines from file using Ansible module for Windows and UNIX Systems
I want to check and extract all the lines that contain the ERROR word in an Ansible playbook so that I can process them after with a non case sensitive pattern.
And I need to do that on Windows and Linux systems.
The lineinfile module I tried doesn't allow me to extract the full line and doesn't do the job when multiple lines with the error word need to be extracted from a single file.
I made some research and the most appropriate solution I found is to use grep via the command module but I'll prefer using a dedicated module, moreover I'm still stuck for Windows logs processing.

Does How to search for a string in a Remote File using Ansible answer your question?

Yomu really helped me ! Thanks a lot for the discovery of this new module ! :)
